# Проблема с установкой libpqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio

Скачал в `github` версию бибилиотеки `7.8.1`.

Установка шла по гайду на ютубе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDiC1Wja6Og&t=603s&ab_channel=Instituteofmarxism-leninism.

На этапе установки через `visual studio`, при сборке `install`, возникает ошибка `MSB3073`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Процесс, после которого пояляеться ошибка]
Пытался переустановить с `разными версиями`. После первой переустановки сборка `произошла`, но с `ошибками`. После сборка не происходила и появлялась ошибка `MSB3073`.
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ставить в program files либы - сомнительное занятие. Поменяли бы путь.

Comment: Или из vcpkg поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо поменять путь сборки `CMake` из `program files` в иную папку.